# Writing to a File, Adding an Additional Space

Tags: python, list, file, iteration, markov-chains

I am creating a Markov text generator that generates haikus.
The function to generate the haiku itself will generate 100 haikus using a for loop. They may look something like:

line1
line2
line3 
line1
line2
line3
line1
line2
line3

When I try writing these lines to the file, I want to include a space between each haiku, so it looks like:

```
line1
line2
line3 

line1
line2
line3

line1
line2
line3
```

How would I make this happen while writing to the file?

Also, sometimes it would not preserve the format...
sometimes, it's written as line1line2line3

How would I structure my loop?

I've tried:

```
def writeToFile():
    with open("results.txt", "w") as fp:
        count = 0
        for haiku in haikuList:
            for line in haiku:
                for item in line:
                    fp.write(str(item))
                    count += 1
        print "There are", count, "lines in your file."
```

haikuList looks like:

```
[[line1,
  line2,
  line3],
 [line1,
  line2,
  line3],
 [line1,
  line2,
  line3],
 [line1,
  line2,
  line3]]
```

Comment: When this is finished, I would love if you would send, a nice haiku to me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) like this:

```
def writeToFile():
    with open("results.txt", "w") as fp:
        fp.write('{}\n'.format('\n\n'.join(['\n'.join(haiku) for haiku in haikuList])))
        print "There are {} lines in your file.".format(len(haikuList)*3 + len(haikuList)-1)
```

This will print each line from each haiku separated by a single new line character. `str.join()` is also used to add new lines between each haiku. With [`file.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file.write#file.write) you need to add in the new line if you want it, so I have used [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to do that.

Finally, the number of lines written to the file will be the same as the length of the `haikuList` multiplied by 3 plus `len(haikuList) - 1` for the new lines between each haiku, so you don't need a counter for that.

One other thing, rather than accessing a variable external to the function, you should pass the haiku list into the `writeToFile()` function:

```
def writeToFile(haikuList):
    with open("results.txt", "w") as fp:
        fp.write('{}\n'.format('\n\n'.join(['\n'.join(haiku) for haiku in haikuList])))
        print "There are {} lines in your file.".format(len(haikuList)*3 + len(haikuList)-1)
```

Then call it like this:

```
writeToFile(haikuList)
```

Comment: Hi, so maybe I worded my question a little bit wrong. This works out great in terms of getting each haiku on separate lines. However, I'm looking for a blank line in between each haiku and also for each line of the haiku to be on a separate line itself. I'm editing my question to make it more clear!

Comment: @natalien: you could try to adapt the answer to your change of requirements. I have updated the answer which is to use `'\n'.join()` instead of `' '.join()` and to add an extra new line between haikus.

Comment: yeah, I was just confused about how to organize that. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put an `fp.write("\n")` after the `for line` loop; this will add a blank line at the end of each haiku.

If you need to add a space after each item, you could add `fp.write(" ")` after `fp.write(str(item))`.

Comment: or `fp.write(' '.join(line))` (he could use `len(items)` instead of incrementing  by one for every item)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each haiku in your haiku list is a `list` of `str` or `unicode`, you could do something like this a bit more concisely.

```
def writeToFile():
    with open("results.txt", "w") as fp:
        count = 0
        for haiku in haikuList:
            fp.write(" ".join(haiku) + "\n"):
            count += len(haiku)
        print "There are", count, "lines in your file."
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually made some edits to my question. Realized that I wasn't so clear before!